# Problem to detect security script like X-Frame through .htaccess file in WordPress and how to trace and find the problem?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I transferred my WordPress website from a hosting company to a virtual machine. I want to add some security scripts like X-Frame, CSP, and HSTS. Before that, I edited the .htaccess file from the cPanel and it worked well.
Now, I added the same script in the current .htaccess file in the VM but when I check with this site [X-Frame Online Check](https://www.site24x7.com/sv/tools/x-frame-options.html), I received a "Couldn't find X-Frame" message.

```
Couldn't find the X-Frame-Options headers in the response headers.
```

This is my .haccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDo>
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

How can I find the problem and trace this issue?

Comment: Start by verifying that mod_headers is actually available?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [help/on-topic]: This sounds more like a server setup question, not programming. https://serverfault.com, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com are better fits for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Issue was fixed with enable `mod_headers`